# How to set up environmental variable in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, jdk

I have never used Ubuntu before. How do I go about setting an environmental variable that points to JDK? I installed it on my Desktop. I typed in "EXPORT JAVA_HOME=~/Desktop/jdk" in the command prompt but it didn't work.

Comment: Commands are case sensitive in Linux. The correct command is `export`.

Comment: Side note: I would generally try to work with absolute paths (/home/user234822/Desktop/jdk).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to xpt's answer:

JAVA_HOME is used internally for some things by the Java runtime. In order to run `java` or `javac` or other commands to start with, you need to add the directory those command are in to your path. For example:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/Desktop/jdk/bin
```

Comment: @xpt if it is a good catch, it deserves an upvote.

Comment: there you go...

Answer (score 1):

It should work at least in the command prompt session that you just set. Else your `~/Desktop/jdk` might not be the correct setting.

To be cautious, do the following:

1. Open up a command prompt
2. Type in `export JAVA_HOME=~/Desktop/jdk`
3. Try run `java`, it should be working by now.

If so, do the following:

1. Still under the command prompt.
2. Type `echo "export JAVA_HOME=~/Desktop/jdk" >> ~/.bashrc
3. Log off and log back in
4. Open up a command prompt
5. Try run `java`, it should be working by now.
6. Anything else (e.g. eclipse) should also be working by now.

HTH

Comment: I think by default Eclipse uses a JRE that it comes with anyway?

Comment: Technically speaking, you should actually have the `export` in your `.bash_profile` and have `.bash_profile` source your `.bashrc` on login. (.bashrc is generally sourced on spawning a shell - so an update to the file [as you suggest] should mean that a logout/in isn't necessary - just open a new shell, .bash_profile is sourced on login). I approved an edit to correct "EXPORT" to "export", but others must approve before it's updated.

Comment: thanks @nerdwaller. Yeah, `export` incorrectly use as `EXPORT` might be the reason why OP failed.